# Not Null issue with Redgate Datacompare 10 API

Tags: .net-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

Need some pointers with my continuous integration project using the redgate Comparison SDK 10 as Im  pulling my hair out atm :-(

I have three databases, lets call them SourceDB1, SourceDB2 and Target.

Target and SourceDB2 will have the exact same schema while SourceDB1 will be missing some columns

I want to run a data compare so where the columns exist in SourceDB1 I use that data, and where columns don't exist I get the data from SourceDB2.

I can't just run two seperate datacompares as if any of the columns which don't exist in SourceDB1 are not null columns the code will fail.

Any pointers on this would be most grateful as Im a bit stucky :-)

Thanks

Comment: I don't know that the RedGate software is capable of, but my gut tells me not this. Effectively you're saying that you want to read two records and aggregate them into one before running the compare against the target -- this is going to require some custom code. It's not terribly difficult, but custom nevertheless.

Comment: Could you explain what the two sources are and why their schemas differ? I'm not sure I get how this relates to continuous integration